# Run and install packages from local folder QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, file-path

I use QGIS in my work and sometimes need install python libraries for plugins to work but I don't have write access to C:/ where QGIS and python is installed (OSGeo4W).
Is there a way I can install pip to a local write folder so I can install and run libraries from local path?